# MongoDB $where optional field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm creating a MongoDB query returning the users whose birthday is today, so I created this JS function in the $where statement:

```
function() {
    if (! this.birthday.getMonth) {return false;}

    return this.birthday.getMonth() == 1
    && this.birthday.getDate() == 1
}
```

Unfortunately, the if statement doesn't seem work as I have an error if the birthday field isn't set for a document:

```
JS Error: TypeError: this.birthday has no properties nofile_18
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: You can check for null on this.birthday however why are you doing this via a $where?

Comment: can you include an example of document structure you are querying against?  i.e. db.collection.findOne() so we can see what you are querying against?

Comment: @Sammaye I'm using where because it's the only way I can retrieve the day and the month from a date in order to see if it's the user's birthday.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky This collection is too big to be displayed here. 'birthday' is a date field.

Comment: not the whole collection, a single document.  Date field to what precision?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get away from $where without changing your schema (e.g. `birthday: {day: nn, month: nn, year: nnnn}`) or doing a lt/gt query for every single year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem prepending the $where statement by [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/). It now works as it should, even when the 'birthday' field is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the birthday field is stored as type Date or ISODate, you can use aggregation framework to make the correct comparison.  I think it will be faster than $where which launches a javascript shell.

```
// construct "thisMonth" variable which is current month as a number
// and thisDay which is current date of the month as a number
> var thisMonth = 5;
> var thisDay = 1;
> db.people.aggregate( [ 
        {$project:{month:{$month:"$birthday"}, date:{$dayOfMonth:"$birthday"}}},
        {$match: {month:thisMonth, date: thisDay}}
  ] )
```

Comment: Because he stores year with the date which complicates finding it since they could have been born in 1988 but this year is 2013

Comment: yeah, this is why I ask for the document - hard to visualize that sort of thing correctly sometimes!  changed it to agg framework which should work.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky i'll give it a try and let you know if it works even when the $birthday field is absent from the document.

Comment: you can add {$match:{birthday:{$exists:true}}} as the first stage to filter out those.